# How to create DNS TXT record?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns, network-programming

I want to create dns TXT record type programmatically by python code.
I did not find any data of how doing it or what is the specific format of TXT record.

Here is how I tried to create TXT record by python:

```
    # copy the id of the request
    packet+=self.data[:2]
    # Add the flags of response
    packet+= "\x81\x80"
    # Questions and Answers Counts
    packet+='\x00\x01'
    packet+='\x00\x01'

    #No records follow
    packet+='\x00\x00'

    # Additional records follow
    packet+='\x00\x00'
    #packet+='\x00\x01'

    (urlList,urlDataLength) = DecodeQuery(self.data)
    urlPosition = urlDataLength

    # Original Domain Name Question
    packet+=self.data[12:12+urlDataLength+4]

    # Pointer to domain name
    packet+='\xc0\x0c'                                             

    #response type ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    # Response type (TXT)
    packet+='\x00\x10'

    #CLASS
    packet+='\x00\x01'
    #TTL
    packet+='\x00\x00\x02\x58'
    #Data Length
    packet+='\x00\x04'
    #txt length
    packet+='\x04'
    packet+= 'hi'.encode('hex')
```

Comment: This? http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/txt.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What good would it be for you to have a TXT record composed in your script? Do you want to write a DNS server in python? Because only DNS servers are composing DNS packets with reply records...

Comment: "I want to create dns TXT record type programmatically by python code." Use the dnspython library it will abstract for you all the needed details. Your snippet of code is full of problems (there are no URLs in DNS, packets can use name compression or not, there is no "hex" encoding, etc.). If you don't want to learn RFC1034 + 1035 fully multiple times to understand the DNS protocol, then don't bother going so low-level, just use the dnspython library that gives you a good high level interface.

Answer (score 1):

From [dnslib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dnslib) (dns.py)

```
class TXT(RD):
    """
        DNS TXT record. Pass in either a single string, or a tuple/list of strings.

        >>> TXT('txtvers=1')
        "txtvers=1"
        >>> TXT(('txtvers=1',))
        "txtvers=1"
        >>> TXT(['txtvers=1',])
        "txtvers=1"
        >>> TXT(['txtvers=1','swver=2.5'])
        "txtvers=1","swver=2.5"
        >>> a = DNSRecord()
        >>> a.add_answer(*RR.fromZone('example.com 60 IN TXT "txtvers=1"'))
        >>> a.add_answer(*RR.fromZone('example.com 120 IN TXT "txtvers=1" "swver=2.3"'))
        >>> print(a)
        ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: ...
        ;; flags: rd; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
        ;; ANSWER SECTION:
        example.com.            60      IN      TXT     "txtvers=1"
        example.com.            120     IN      TXT     "txtvers=1" "swver=2.3"
    """
```